# USB devices vs Chromebook close cover

Tags: usb, audio, chromebook

I have a Chromebook, and I use a USB-based pair of headphones (high-quality ones). I listen to music on my Chromebook, but when I close the lid on my desk, music stops. I understand that all USB activity is stopped when I close the lid. How can I keep the music going when I close the lid ? This is a Chromebook that can't get Linux fully installed on it (just CHrouton).

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Chromebooks dislike giving users any power settings. (Or any control what so ever, but I digress.)

The only way I can think of is using a chrome extension called "Keep Awake."

[Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keep-awake/bijihlabcfdnabacffofojgmehjdielb?hl=en) is the link to the extension.

Disclaimer: If you install that extension, you do so at your own risk as I have never used it nor can I vouch that it will work.

Hope this helps!